# Need a duplicate Drupal 7 site with different theme same DB, any suggestions?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

We have a Drupal 7 site on our root domain and want to set up a subdomain or subdirectory with all the same content but without header/footer branding so our partners can add iframes of our product sections to their websites. We need to use the same database so all content gets updated globally.

Any recommendations on where to start? appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change theme programmatically with a custom module

```
function MYMODULE_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['myendpoint/path/%'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Custom rendering page external',
    'page callback'    => 'custom_rendering_on_endpoint',
    'page arguments'   => array(2),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type'             => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;

}


function custom_rendering_on_endpoint($nid = null)

  $node = node_load($nid);
  $view = node_view($node, 'full');
  print drupal_render($view);
}

function  MYMODULE_custom_theme(){
   $menu = menu_get_item();
   if($menu['path'] == 'myendpoint/path/%'){
       return "custom_theme_name";
   }
   return "default_theme_name";  
}
```

NB : change page.tpl.php to remove all regions and parts you don't want to be displayed into you custom theme ($header, $footer , etc..)

**It should be noted, that the theme you want to activate must be enabled first at admin/appearance.**

Documentation : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7.x

Comment: Thank You! This is exactly what I was looking for.